# MongoDB db.getREplicationInfo() with Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, groovy

I'm trying to perform the db.getReplicationInfo() request with the Java Mongodb driver. First I see that

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(host, port)
DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "admin" )
db.command("getReplicationInfo")
```

Doesn't work. Response is

```
{ .."ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "no such cmd: getReplicationInfo" , "bad cmd" : { "getReplicationInfo" : true}}
```

while in a Mongo shell

```
use admin
db.getREplicationInfo()
```

return the desired data.

After I can read for other Mongo driver (Python or Ruby) that the getReplicationInfo() command is not implemented and to perform it I have to code my own method reflecting the code defined by getReplicationInfo shell (viewable running db.getReplicationInfo without bracket in shell)

Does it true using Java driver or there is a tips to call getReplicationInfo() command ?

If I have to do that I don't know how to translate

```
 if (db.system.namespaces.findOne({name:"local.oplog.rs"}) != null) {
    oplog = 'oplog.rs';
}
else if (db.system.namespaces.findOne({name:"local.oplog.$main"}) != null) {
    oplog = 'oplog.$main';
}
```

using the Java/Groovy and mongo driver, can anybody help me ? Does anyone already write a similar function in Java ?

Thanks

Comment: "getReplicationInfo" is not a database command, it's just a function written into the shell that runs some queries on the "system" namespace. You can see this by just typing `db.getReplicationInfo` into the shell directly and without the trailing brackets `()`. Looks like you already have, by the partial listing. But asking someone to translate JavaScript to Java code is not a valid topic for a question here.

Comment: DOn't want any complete translation, just the db.system.namespaces.findOne Java version

Comment: "system.namespaces"  is the name of the collection. `.findOne()` as a query method. No translation to Java required.

Comment: You mean that  `DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("system.namespaces")`  and `collection.findOne(new BasicDBObject().put("name", "local.oplog.rs")` or `collection.findOne(new BasicDBObject().put("name", 'local.oplog.$main')` return expected documents?

Comment: Well yes. Don't forget the first line of that script selects the "local" database though as well. It does honestly stun me the amount of times I hear "But how to do that in Java". Apart from constructing DBObject members there is generally nothing else to translate.

Comment: Yes It works fine, you are right about Java driver and the standard Mongo shell language, finally syntax are similar, just have to work with DBObject, BSONTimestamp and other Java object oriented transformation.
Thank you